# du is giving me inconsistent results depending on argument order

Tags: macos, command-line, du

I'm running Darwin (Mac OS X 10.11.2 - the current version of El Capitan) on my Mac Book Pro, but this is about a standard command line utility, du.

I am getting inconsistent results from `du`:

```
21:19 % du -sk
677876  .
21:19 % du -sk .
677876  .
21:19 % du -sk *
276464  aaa
61440   bbb
339968  ccc
21:19 % du -sk * .
276464  aaa
61440   bbb
339968  ccc
4   .
```

All normal so far - here comes the surprise

```
21:19 % du -sk . *
677876  .
0   aaa
0   bbb
0   ccc
```

I don't expect to know why it is doing this - but how do I find out why it is doing this?

A comment asked for the output of `ls -l` and that's a great suggestion. Here is the output of `ls -lai@`:

```
total 7
 19867848 drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  204 Feb  9 21:09 .
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID     36 
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID     8 
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID     36 
 19867847 drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102 Jun 19  2014 ..
    com.apple.backup.SnapshotNumber   2 
    com.apple.backup.SnapshotVersion      1 
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotCompletionDate     16 
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotStartDate  16 
    com.apple.backupd.SnapshotType    1 
    com.apple.backupdelta.IsMobileBackup      3 
    com.apple.backupdelta.SizeEstimate    9 
 19868010 drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102 Dec 21 08:24 aaa
    com.apple.s stem.Security    68 
 19867861 drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  admin  102 Jan 27  2014 bbb
    com.apple.backupdelta.MoveChecked     3 
 19871640 drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102 Jun 19  2014 ccc
    com.apple.FinderInfo     32
```

Comment: can you post `ls -la`? wonder if that has something to do with rights or something

Comment: @aaaaaa: Question edited with answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your using `du` in a Time Machine backup folder.

Per `du` man page:

> Directories having multiple hard links (typically Time Machine backups) are counted a single time per du execution.

So I think the `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` files are hard links, and since they were counted in the result of the `.`, they won't be counted again in the result for `aaa`, `bbb` or `ccc`. That's also why the output of `du -sk * .` doesn't show 677876, but only 4; the total of all the specified files/folders can't go over 677876.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html